# Enabling a stylesheet after screen resize? Not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
if ((screen.width>=1024)) {
$('link[title=theme800]')[0].disabled=true;
$('link[title=theme]')[0].disabled=false;
}
if ((screen.width<1024)) {
$('link[title=theme]')[0].disabled=true;
$('link[title=theme800]')[0].disabled=false;
}
});
```

My html page:

```
<link title = "theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="theme.css" />
<link title = "theme800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="theme800.css" />
```

Okay, I was testing my site in different screen sizes. For some reason, the 2nd stylesheet (theme800) is not loading in IE and Chrome when I'm in '<1024' mode, it works with Firefox tho.
I did give everything title and everything. Again, it works in Firefox but in other browsers it doesn't work. How do I make it work in other browsers?
Help!

Thanks.

Comment: Try switching out the href of the link element.

Comment: nothing in your code would prevent `link` from loading.... more likely you have same css selectors and last one loaded prevails. In fact your code won't do anything

Comment: I did try switching it to href, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely be much better off using css media queries for your situation

Answer (score 0):

As [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) are not widely supported yet, you could also consider loading the stylesheets dynamically. Based on [this example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml), you can try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load_stylesheet(file_name) {
         // Create the stylesheet
        var css_file = document.createElement('link');
        css_file.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        css_file.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        css_file.setAttribute('href', file_name);
         // Append the stylesheet to the document
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css_file);
    }

    if (screen.width >= 1024) {
        load_stylesheet('theme.css');
    } else {
        load_stylesheet('theme800.css');
    }
</script>
```

Note that this is not done with jQuery on purpose, so a stylesheet could be loaded as soon as possible, without waiting for jQuery to load first. Otherwise, there could be a noticeable lag for the users, during which the content would appear bare and without styling.